# extend global with es6 module import

Tags: angular, typescript, dc.js, es6-module-loader

How I can import a js lib that extends the global on some other lib, even though using import statements does not expose any globals? Here's my problem:

```
import * as dc from 'dc';
import 'dc-addons';
```

The problem is dc-addons tooltip-mixin has this code in it:

```
if (typeof dc === 'undefined') {
    return false;
}
```

which actually triggers because "import * as dc" does not put "dc" as a global

Comment: maybe this works: `import * as dc from 'dc'; window.dc = dc; import 'dc-addons';`?